# Heroku environment variables not set in javascript for React/Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, heroku, environment-variables, create-react-app

I've built a Rails-Api with React SPA frontend following [this guide](https://blog.heroku.com/a-rock-solid-modern-web-stack/) (very helpful, would recommend). I'm having issues getting Heroku to set the environment variables in the .env file that React uses for config vars. The values of the file are just set as literally "ENV[...]" instead of evaluating and setting the value. On the Rails side the Heroku ENV vars are being set correctly because I can see them in the console.

```
.env file:
REACT_APP_API_KEY=ENV['API_KEY']
REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN=ENV['AUTH_DOMAIN']
```

```
App.js (top level Component):
console.log(config,process.env);
// which logs:
{
  NODE_ENV: "production"
  REACT_APP_API_KEY: "ENV['API_KEY']"
  REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN: "ENV['AUTH_DOMAIN']"
  ...
}
```

```
Rails Console:
irb(main):001:0> ENV
=> {"LANG"=>"en_US.UTF-8", "NODE_ENV"=>"production",
"API_KEY"=>"<correct-value>", "AUTH_DOMAIN"=>"<correct-value>",......}
```

Is there something I need to do in order to alert Heroku that the ENV vars need to also be set in the .env file for the react app? The tutorial has the Heroku deployment use both the nodejs and ruby buildpacks (in that order). The app is built and then copied into the "public" dir for Rails to serve:

```
package.json
{
  //...
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.9.0",
    "yarn": "1.22.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "yarn --cwd client install && yarn --cwd client build",
    "deploy": "cp -a client/build/. public/",
    "heroku-postbuild": "yarn build && yarn deploy"
  }
}
```

I don't know enough about the internal workings with Heroku's env vars swap.  From what I understand with Create React App... the .env file's contents are [set at build time](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) so it is possible that the js is compiled before Heroku has any chance to inject the env vars. I'm open to suggestion on other ways to do this if this method isn't doable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expand environment variables in `.env` file. When React app is built, it has access to variables in your Heroku dyno, and react-scripts supports referencing them in your `.env` file. [See more in docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#expanding-environment-variables-in-env).

With this in mind, your `.env` file would look like:

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY=$API_KEY
REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN=$AUTH_DOMAIN
```

Assuming `API_KEY` and `AUTH_DOMAIN` variables are set in Heroku.

If you name these variables `REACT_APP_API_KEY` and `REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN` in Heroku in the first place, then they will be picked up by react-scripts directly from the environment (no need for `.env` file then)

**NOTE:** with the above said, it sounds like you are trying to expose secrets in React app. The Create React App docs strongly warns NOT to do that, because:

> Environment variables are embedded into the build, meaning anyone can view them by inspecting your app's files.

Comment: thanks Petr... I'll give it a try.  FWIW, this is for the config for Firebase which belongs on the frontend.  I just didn't want to complicate the question more by having that show up.  I def agree with your note.

Comment: Worked perfectly... ended up just prepending the settings with REACT_APP_ and removed everything from the .env file.  Wish I would have found this in the docs but happy to be through it with your help!